# ExtJS4 set values in controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have an ExtJS4 application in which one controller (ControllerA) is loading another (ControllerB). Controller A has some user input that I need to set in ControllerB so that when ControllerB loads pulldowns it can by default jump those pulldowns to the correct value.

I can pass the values fine from ControllerA:

```
itemClick: function itemClick(distributor, product) {
  var ctrlr = this.getController('Internal.controller.Popup');
  var win = ctrlr.openWin(distributor, product);
  ctrl.init();
}
```

The openwin function gets the values, I am just not sure how in that function I can save these values so that other functions in ControllerB can check if they exist and if so set the comboboxes appropriately ex:

```
openWin: function openWin(distributor, product) {
  var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    ...
  });
  // Somehow set distributor and product
  return win;
}
loadDistributorBox: function loadDistributorBox(str) {
  //Listener for Ajax load of combobox values
  var combobox = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox')[0];
  var items = str.getRange();
  if (isset(distributor)) {
    // Move the pulldown to the item that matches
  } else {
    // Show the default first value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**

Init the controller before you call any other function.

```
itemClick: function itemClick(distributor, product) {
  var ctrlr = this.getController('Internal.controller.Popup');
  ctrl.init();
  var win = ctrlr.openWin(distributor, product);
}
```

**Second**

Check if you have the arguments and set them. For that you can use the **[setValues](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-setValues)** methods of the baseform

```
openWin: function openWin(distributor, product) {
  var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    ...
  });
  var form = win.down('form').getForm();
      setObj = {};
  if (distributor) {
     setObj['DistributorFieldName'] = distributor;
  }

  if (product) {
     setObj['ProductFieldName'] = product;
  }
  // set the values
  form.setValue(setObj );

  return win;
}
```